# How to install react-bootstrap v0.32.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to install react-bootstrap v0.32.4? I look at react bootstrap 3 documentation, but there is only: `npm install --save react-bootstrap`

Comment: npm install --save react-bootstrap@0.32.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the desired version like `react-bootstrap@0.32.4` at the end of `npm install --save`

I.E

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap@0.32.4
```